# How to store the file that get from S3 to /tmp/ in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to store the PDF file that I retrived it from S3 to /tmp/ in Lambda but it shows the error that No such file or directory

Here is my code

`s3_1.Bucket(bucket_name).download_file(key_file, "/tmp/filename.pdf")`

And the error shows that :

*FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp\filename.pdf.1261Ec23'*

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.download_file('BUCKET_NAME', 'folder/filename.pdf', '/tmp/filename.pdf')
```

Working code and this way you can trace error and verify download part:

```py
import json
import urllib.parse
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


print('Loading function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    s3.download_file('fileuploadprocess', 'Document/SampleFile', '/tmp/SampleFile')
    
    try:
        response = s3.upload_file('/tmp/SampleFile', 'fileuploadprocess', 'Document122/SampleFile')
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: still got the same error that  "No such file or directory: '/tmp\\filename.pdf.dF603d39'"

Comment: Check your aws creditional whether they have permission or not and also role